# [GraphQL error]: Context Creation Failed during Signin with React & Apollo

Tags: react-native, apollo, react-apollo

initially my authentication was working ok. then i left the computer on and came back to code again and this time, my authentication failed with following message

[GraphQL error]: Message: Context creation failed: Your session has ended. Please sign in again, Location: undefined, Path: undefined

i had set an expiry for the token. I tried to clear the cache before signin but still get the above error.

below is my code for the signin function

```
 _handleSubmit = (values, bag, signIn) => {
    signIn({
      variables: {
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password
      }
    })
      .then(async ({ data }) => {
        if (data && data.signIn.token) {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", data.signIn.token);
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        bag.setSubmitting(false);
        bag.setErrors(err);
      });
  };
```

my stack is apollo, mongodb, react-native. i suspected the problem might be the caching. i tried to clear the cache but clearning the cache on Expo by pressing "R" but i still can't log in.

[Update] the error is due to jwt token expired. I get this error when I console.log(@res, res)  in getUser function

{ TokenExpiredError: jwt expired...

funny thing though is i created a new jwt token for each signin. below is my codes for createToken and getUser

Anyone encountered such situation before? How do you solve it?

```
const createToken = (user, expiresIn) => {
  const { _id, email } = user;
  //creturn jwt.sign({ _id, email }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn });
  return jwt.sign({ _id, email }, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
};


const getUser = async token => {
  if (token) {
    try {
      const res = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
      console.log("@res ", res);
      return res;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("@error ", error);
      throw new AuthenticationError(
        "Your session has ended. Please sign in again"
      );
    }
  }
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i ran in my ApolloClient's authLink...

```
await AsyncStorage.removeItem("token");
```

then commented it out, n it worked again!

```
const authLink = setContext(async (req, { headers }) => {
  // await AsyncStorage.removeItem("token");
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
  console.log("@token ", token);

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `${token}` : ""
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you. To me I was sending undefined token in App.js, so I'm sending an empty object in graphql headers now; which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you don't send `undefined` as a token in headers on the frontend. Usually in App.js when an unauthorized user tries to login.

Answer (score 0):

i also get this error so basically when you write the expire jwt token in playground in backend side it will give you this error for solving write the valid token in HTTPs Header in graphql playground.